# Using apply on a Matrix

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to apply a function to 32 columns.  I have a 32X32 matrix I have named nfl_data which was read in from Excel.  It seems that the apply function will be able to apply a function to all columns.  I'm trying to add the values of a column and divide by 13, and then take the average of the reduced column.  Here is my code:

```
x <- solve(nfl_data)
rm <- apply(x, 2, function(i) round((1/13)*(sum(nfl_data[,i])) + mean(x[,i]),digits=2))
```

I am receiving an error:

> Error in .subset(x, j) : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Also, when I use str(rm) I get:

> num [1:32] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...

What should I do to not get the error and then actually have numeric values?

Comment: Please make this reproducible by adding example data that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at your data, I simulate one as below and provide one solution. For the error using `apply` in your OP, I think it is likely that you have both positive and negative indices.

```
# simulate the dataset:
nfl_data = rnorm(n=32*32, mean=4, sd=0.5)  
nfl_data = matrix(nfl_data, nr=32, nc=32)
head(nfl_data)

# your codes:
x <- solve(nfl_data)
myfun = function(i) round( (1/13)*(sum(nfl_data[,i])) + mean(x[,i]), digits=2 )

# alternative way:
rm = numeric(32)
for (i in 1:32){
  rm[i]=myfun(i)
}

# check results:
rm
```

Comment: Using `rm` as a data-object name seems rather unwise.